# Ошибка при тестировании: AssertionError: No templates used to render the response

Tags: python, django

Помогите, пожалуйста. Просмотрел кучу информации, но та, которая бы помогла мне так и не нашёл.
Возникает ошибка при тестировании AssertionError: No templates used to render the response. Вот код самого класса:

```
class ProductsListViewTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['categories.json', 'goods.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.products = Product.objects.all()

    def test_list(self):
        path = reverse('products:index')
        response = self.client.get(path)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.context_data['title'], 'Store - Каталог')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'products/products.html')
        self.assertEqual(list(response.context_data['object_list']), list(self.products[:3]))

    def test_list_with_category(self):
        category = ProductCategory.objects.first()
        path = reverse('products:category', kwargs={'category_id': category.id})
        response = self.client.get(path)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, HTTPStatus.OK)
        self.assertEqual(response.context_data['title'], 'Store - Каталог')
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'products/products.html')
        self.assertEqual(
            list(response.context_data['object_list']),
            list(self.products.filter(category_id=category.id))
        )
```